# How can I prevent certain links from making my page revert back to old information?

Tags: javascript, api, openweathermap

I'm building a weather app, it's working to the point that I can search anywhere and get the weather, as well as a forecast for the next 15 hours.
I'm trying to add a current location feature which is mostly working. The problem arises when I click the fahrenheit or celsius link next to the temperature, it reverts back to the placeholder city, or the previous city that I typed in.
Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: It will be helpful if you put your code in question. May be if the href attribute of links is having "#" as value.

Comment: This is the HTML:
 <span class="temperature" id="temperature"> 
                    </span><span class="units"><a href="#" class="celsius-link" id="celsius-link">°C</a> | <a href="#" class="farenheit-link" id="farenheit-link">°F</a>
            </span>

When I search a city I can click on both links and it will swap between temperatures which is what I want it to do 

but when I click the current button, it displays the temperature in celsius (that's the default I've set) as well as the place name, weather icon etc but when I click the F° link it reverts back to the last city entered

Answer (score 0):

You can put "javascript:void(0)" in place of "#" in href, it will prevent redirection on click of the links.

```
<span class="temperature" id="temperature"> </span><span class="units"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="celsius-link" id="celsius-link">°C</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="farenheit-link" id="farenheit-link">°F</a> </span>
```